# Django Rest Framework deployed under subdirectory proxy urlpattern missmatch

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to deploy a small API using a subdirectory on the server. Usually if I do the following config it works fine:

```
location /iframe/api/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

The funny thing is that for static files it seems to work, because I get back proper styling for the rest framework, but for every single urlpattern it also transfers the iframe/api which isn't ideal and basically not a single API route is matched.

I tried to add `proxy_redirect off` but still no avail. Any idea why isn't this working as expected? How should I deploy a rest framework API under a sub-directory?

Also tried to use `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME='/iframe/api'`, however I still get the same issue that the URL isn't matched `The current path, iframe/api/, didn’t match any of these.`

Comment: if I modify 
```proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;``` the paths are correctly found, but the css for rest framework isn't working anymore :)))

Answer (score 0):

After quite a few hours spend debugging I was able to solve it kinda, but it required multiple ways to do it. If you have better solution feel free to post it!

First you need the trailing / for proxy_pass so the `/iframe/api` isn't transfered.

```
location /iframe/api/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  client_max_body_size 0;
}
```

This solved that part that the URLs wasn't being matched. For some strange reason I wasn't able to solve the static file sharing directly trough the reverse proxy, so what I ended up was to bind both media and static files to a volume on the main machine and serve them with alias

```
location /media {
  alias /home/user/path_to_media/media;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /static {
  alias /home/user/path_to_media/static;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

You also need to set the `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` in the settings file otherwise the urls generated by the rest framework won't work properly.